# Get all records if table type parameter is null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle, I want to get all values of column if the table valued parameter is null otherwise only the matched records.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE pr_Employees (
    lastnames IN LastName,
    rowCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
Select * from emp where lastname in (
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(lastnames)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure pr_employees
    ( lastnames in lastname
    , rowcursor out sys_refcursor )
is
begin
    open rowcursor for
        select * from emp
        where  lastname in
               ( select column_value from table(lastnames) )
        or     lastnames is empty;
end pr_employees;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried above one, If I passed lastnames is null it is returning 0 records.

Comment: How is `last name` defined? I made mine a `table of varchar2(60)`. How are you setting the parameter value when you call it? I've handled the case where you pass an empty collection, not a collection of null values.